# multiple parameters to const React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, socket.io, constants

I want to parse 2 parameters to a const, what is the best practice in React? I want username and message instead of data.

```
socket.on('updateChat', function (username, message) {
    addMessage(username, message);
}

const addMessage = data => {
   this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, data]});
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> data is a parameter of addMessage, instead of that you can use as many
>   parameter as you want.

```
socket.on('updateChat', function (username, message) {
    addMessage(username, message);
}

const addMessage = (username, message) => {
   this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, data]});
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!